# IOS App Building - using IOS 7 resources

Tags: ios

I am going to begin to build an app but the resources I have (books) are for IOS 7 - the current version is IOS 9 and I was wondering if it would still be ok to use this book or if it will now be irrelevant - or have hugely out of date information in it. I've done some research but I am not 100% what the changes have been for development from IOS 7 to IOS 9.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: do you mean IOS? If not you should probably explain what ISO is

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - it is meant to be IOS, it was a typo. I'll edit my question to make sure there is no more confusion

Comment: Parts of it will be out of date, and parts will be OK.  It all depends on what part of the API you want to make use of.  Code written for iOS 7 will, for the most part, still run on iOS 9, and Xcode will warn you of deprecated API calls.